サービスアカウントキーを使用しないGoogle Workspace APIの呼び出し
サービスアカウントの認証方法についてのご質問です。
こちらのドキュメントの様に、Google Workspace ドメイン全体の権限の委任を行おうとしています。
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation?hl=ja#python
質問：
秘密鍵ファイル（jsonまたはp12ファイル）を使用したアクセスができることは確認できたのですが、秘密鍵を使わない方法はございますでしょうか。
背景：
Google WorkspaceのSAMLログの保管期間を延ばすために、ログをGCSへ格納する処理をCloudFunctionsにて実装しようとしています。
Google Workspace APIを用いて、SAMLログをGCSへ格納するには、ドメイン全体の権限をサービス アカウントに委任し、Admin SDK Directory サービス オブジェクトをインスタンス化する必要がある認識ですが
秘密鍵は管理にリスクが生じるため、可能ならばCloudFunctionsに付与するデフォルトの権限でアクセスしたいと考えているため。
よろしくお願いいたします。
